# How to do thread interacting?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I want to use multithreading (low -level threading) but i am running into a problem. The problem is that because of at least wait method will be called by one thread and notifyAll will be called by another thread the problem is that any time i run the program it seems to me that notifyAll is called before wait so i "will wait forever".

My code is as below :

```
public class Reader extends Thread {

    Calculator c;

    public Reader(Calculator cal) {
        c=cal;
    }

    public void run (){
        synchronized(c) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for calculation");
                c.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            System.out.println("Total is:" +c.total);      
        }       
    }  

    public static void main (String[] a) {

        Calculator calculator=new Calculator();

        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Reader(calculator).start();
    }
}

class Calculator implements Runnable {

    int total;

    public void run()  {
        synchronized(this) {    
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
                total=total+i;
            }       
            notifyAll();    
        }
    }
}
```

What i get here as output is 5 times in a row waiting for calculation so i never reach the statement "the total is the total.

I am trying to figure it out how to solve the problem but still not finding a solution. If anybody has any clue what to do i will appreciate a lot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually executing the Calculator runnable, the code you have won't calculate a total or notify anything. Start up a new thread using the Calculator:

```
new Thread(calculator).start();
```

following the line where you initialize the calculator local variable. This will let the calculator start working while the main thread is starting up the readers.

Still it's likely the calculator may finish before the readers can start waiting, and the readers will end up waiting forever for a notification that will never come. Make a condition variable, in this case adding a boolean flag to Calculator, that you initialize to false and set to true once it's done calculating (by the notifyAll, before leaving the synchronized block). Have the readers wait in a loop:

```
synchronized(c) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Waiting for calculation");
        while (!c.finished) {
            c.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    System.out.println("Total is:" +c.total);
}
```

This way, in case the calculator finishes before the readers start, the readers will tell from the condition variable that the calculator is finished and they won't wait.

It's a good practice to always call the wait method in a loop because

a) when the thread receives the notification it doesn't have the lock, in the time between when the thread is notified and the time it reacquires the lock the state of the system could change due to other threads' actions (not the case in this example), and

b) you can't rely on the termination of wait meaning that the thread received a notification.

With the above changes the program finishes normally with this output:

```
Waiting for calculation
Total is:4950
Waiting for calculation
Total is:4950
Waiting for calculation
Total is:4950
Waiting for calculation
Total is:4950
Waiting for calculation
Total is:4950
```

Here's the complete revised code:

```
public class Reader extends Thread {

    Calculator c;

    public Reader(Calculator cal) {
        c=cal;
    }

    public void run (){
        synchronized(c) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for calculation");
                while (!c.finished) {
                    c.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            System.out.println("Total is:" +c.total);      
        }       
    }  

    public static void main (String[] a) {

        Calculator calculator=new Calculator();
        new Thread(calculator).start();

        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Reader(calculator).start();
    }
}

class Calculator implements Runnable {

    int total;
    boolean finished;

    public void run()  {
        synchronized(this) {    
            finished = false;
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
                total=total+i;
            }       
            notifyAll();    
            finished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just have one question . I am aware of that every thread of execution begins as an instance of class Thread. So when i extend thread class let say as i have done with reader class so to instaniate a thread (so passing from new state to runnable state of thread object) we do somethink like this:new Reader.start() . so now i am wondering why my code is not instaniated a new instance of thread for calculator class when i do simply new Reader(calculator).start(); It looks like it has to work but it is nok working obviously. Can you please clear to me that

Comment: @ENIO: you didn't create a thread for the Calculator. i'm not clear what you're confused about. if you pass a Runnable as a constructor arg to a new Thread then the thread will execute that Runnable. but Reader overrides Thread's run method and won't result in running the Calculator. It's better to avoid subclassing Thread at all, it just causes confusion.

Comment: What's with all the bumping?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest some clarification on what you expect the final result to be. Apparently 500? Not sure :P

In any case, I recommend using Java Executors. They're default Java classes that deal with executing threads in an organized way. Try this:

```
public class Example {
    public static class Calculator implements Runnable {
        private int result = 0;

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                result++;
            }

            System.out.println("Done. Result = " + result);
        }

        public int getResult() {
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Calculator c = new Calculator();
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(c);
        executorService.submit(c);
        executorService.submit(c);
        executorService.submit(c);
        executorService.submit(c);
    }
}
```

This give me the following:

```
Done. Result = 100
Done. Result = 200
Done. Result = 300
Done. Result = 400
Done. Result = 500
```

What this code do is create a Single Thread Executor which can run tasks (`Runnable` objects) and uses a single thread for this. Because it uses a single thread every task must wait the one prior to it in order to start.

If you create a Multiple Thread Executor it'll try and run the tasks in as many threads are available and all of those will follow the same principle as the Single Thread one: for every thread a task must wait the one before it to start. But with the Multiple Thread Executor, as the name says, there are multiple threads so this means that the tasks will run concurrently and the same behavior you have now will show up.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Despite you wrote about low level threading, it's clear that your problem can be solved with [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). The point is you can easily make a mistake using `wait` - `notify` calls; but "happens before" relations can be set without calling to `wait`, using `join` method instead.

Full code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Reader extends Thread {

    final Future<Integer> future;

    public Reader(Future<Integer> future) {
        this.future = future;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int result = future.get();
            System.out.println("Total is:" + result);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        ForkJoinPool pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        ForkJoinTask calcTask = pool.submit(calculator);
        ForkJoinTask[] tasks = {
            calcTask,
            pool.submit(new Reader(calcTask)),
            pool.submit(new Reader(calcTask)),
            pool.submit(new Reader(calcTask)),
            pool.submit(new Reader(calcTask)),
            pool.submit(new Reader(calcTask))
        };
        //do something else
        for (ForkJoinTask task : tasks) {
            task.join();
        }
    }
}

class Calculator implements Callable<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            total = total + i;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```